# Read XML Node at different level with same name

Tags: c#, xml

i have an xml, which is have same element name at different level, i try to read it by using this code,

```
 xDoc.Load(url);
     XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes(string.Format("/DirectionsResponse/route"));
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)node;

        kl = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("summary")[0].InnerText;
        kl = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("distance")[0].InnerText;
    }
```

i can read the summary element, but the problem is with the `<distance>` element, it read the first `<distance>` node that it found. I want to read the `<distance>` element that not in `<step>` node.

Can anyone show me how to do it

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN, on `GetElementsByTagName`:

> Returns an XmlNodeList containing a list of all descendant elements
>    that match the specified Name.

It's a *complete sub-tree search*, not a "select subnodes" function. For selecting a single subnode, use `SelectSingleNode`. For a group like your "step" ones, use `SelectNodes` and iterate over them properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectSingleNode` or `SelectNodes` in order to describe elements in XPath just like you have done this at line `XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/DirectionsResponse/route");`.

```
xDoc.Load(url);
XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes(string.Format("/DirectionsResponse/route"));
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)node;

    kl = companyElement.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText; // summary node within current context
    kl = companyElement.SelectSingleNode("distance").InnerText;
}
```

should do the trick.

In my opinion, it is better to use all-purpose XPath `SelectSingleNode` and `SelectNodes` methods everywhere.
If you have any questions, [read more about XPath at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

*By the way*, you can specify `XmlElement` as enumerated type and not convert it explicitly:

```
xDoc.Load(url);
foreach (XmlElement element in xDoc.SelectNodes("/DirectionsResponse/route")) 
{
    kl = element.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText;
    kl = element.SelectSingleNode("distance").InnerText;
}
```